# How can i read this stdClass object in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, stdclass

```
stdClass Object ( 
    [api] => stdClass Object ( 
        [results] => 1 
        [leagues] => stdClass Object ( 
            [1] => stdClass Object ( 
                [league_id] => 1 
                [name] => World Cup 
                [country] => World 
                [country_code] => 
                [season] => 2018 
                [season_start] => 2018-06-14 
                [season_end] => 2018-07-15 
                [logo] => https://media.api-football.com/leagues/1.png 
                [flag] => 
                [standings] => 1 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
)

$data= json_decode($response,false);
```

I must read the element `[league_id]`

I tried to write

```
echo $data->api->leagues[1]->league_id;
```

seeing also the previous examples, but 
nothing is printed, I can't understand what I'm wrong. Could someone help me, thanks? thanks

Comment: @daremachine Where do you see the index `0` in the dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leagues` is an object, not an array, so you need to use `->` to access the property. And since it's a number rather than an identifier, you have to wrap the property name in braces.

```
echo $data->api->leagues->{"1"}->league_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the second parameter from `json_decode` to true, maybe you will access in this way:

```
echo $data['api']['leagues']['1']['league_id'];
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question

Comment: but only in this way? if I leave it so it is not possible to read it?